# How can I determine the input and output impedance in a common base amplifier?

Tags: transistors, bjt, input-impedance, common-base

[image: CB amplifier]

I have been struggling with this simple problem for a week.

I want to find the input and the output impedance.

We were only taught two formulas in our course to find the impedance:

$$Zin= \frac{Vin}{Iin}$$
$$Zout= \frac{Vout}{Iout}$$.

My problem is I don't know how exactly I should apply them. Looking everywhere, no one uses them. All the solutions I could find get the total resistance in the input mesh to find \$Zin\$. Firstly I solved it like this:

Using KVL on the yellow mesh.

$$VBE+ Vin= IE*Rin+ VBE+ re*IE$$
$$Vin=IE*Rin+VBE+ re*IE$$
$$Zin= (IE*Rin+VBE+ re*IE)/IE$$
$$Zout= VRL/IC= RL$$

I know I'm doing something terribly wrong but I can't put my hand on it.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my method?

Comment: Strange circuit.  But from what I see  Zin = (Rin + re) and Zo = ro.

Comment: When in AC analysis ... Zout = Vout (open circuit) / Iout (when output is shorted) ...

Answer (score 1):

Because base and emitter form a diode and, for transistor operation that diode is forward biased you can make a half-decent approximation to the input impedance being \$R_{IN}\$. If you wanted to go deeper you could factor in \$r_E\$ (the impedance of the forward biased diode). That impedance is roughly \$\frac{0.025}{I_C}\$. It's going to be between 1 Ω and 50 Ω normally.

The output impedance is clearly \$R_L\$ in parallel with the impedance presented by the collector. Given that the collector is providing a near constant current signal (i.e. it's a high impedance), we can quite reasonably say as a first approximation that the output impedance is simply \$R_L\$.

If you plotted the transistor slopes on the right-hand side of this common-base PNP characteristic (cut-off region) you would find that the collector impedance will be between about 20 kΩ to maybe 100 kΩ with a bit of hand-waving: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://circuitglobe.com/common-base-connection-cb-configuration.html).